# Why does WordPress reverse conditional statements?

Tags: coding-standards

In WordPress' core code, you often see this:

```
if (1 == $someVar)
```

as opposed to this:

```
if ($someVar == 1)
```

I don't know if the first way is a WordPress-centric style of coding, but I've only noticed it in WP code (either core or 3rd-party code).

Comment: [Yoda conditions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) these are .

Comment: The second way is easier to read; the first will help prevent the single `=` error

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#Yoda_Conditions

Comment: Hrm...how is this off-topic? I've since found from the comments added to my question that it is recommended to code for WP using Yoda conditions per the [Codex] ( http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#Yoda_Conditions)

Comment: @AKTed It's off topic because it's not specific to WordPress, it's a PHP question. From the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq): **not specific to WordPress (even if they happen in its context)**

Comment: @Milo: I thought so at first, but it *is* WordPress specific in the context that WordPress includes it in their Codex as *the way they want it done*. It does qualify as a PHP question, but my question was specifically about noticing it in WP code *a lot*.

Comment: @toscho & Milo: My question adheres to the [faq] in these two respects:
1. It satisfies the section "WordPress - Stack Exchange is for WordPress developers and administrators to ask questions about:"... **development** and management **best practices**
2. Since WordPress lists Yoda conditions in the Coding Standards section of the Codex as a preferred method of coding, it *does not* fall under the faq section "not specific to WordPress (even if they happen in its context)"

Comment: @AKTed Please use [meta] to discuss our scope.

Comment: @toscho: I don't have enough Rep to ask on Meta. Besides, your "closed as off topic..." statement *tells* me to leave "comments..." right here! While I'm sure it's StackExchange's form statement for closing this question, it's effectively *you* who are saying it. So, what's my recourse? I can't yet use WP Meta, and apparently I shouldn't discuss it here (even though "you" told me to!)?

Comment: @AKTed You [need 5 points](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/participate-in-meta). Don’t tell me that’s too much. :)

Comment: I'm so new here that I don't yet have 'em :(

Comment: And to whomever downvoted my question, why? Because you knew something I didn't? If that's the case, *every* question should be downvoted. Meh, through wasting my time on this b.s.

Comment: People sometimes downvote if the question is not particularly useful to the site. Don't take it too personally; it's not like  you have any reputation to loose ;)

Comment: @bungeshea Sorry, but that tag isn't there for that. In fact, it shouldn't be here anyway.

Comment: This question *is* on topic because it pertains to the [documented WordPress coding standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/#yoda-conditions). Reopened and answered as such.

Comment: There you go, nice Title, nice Answer, up-votes, [The Way of the Stack](http://youtu.be/1yVlNqxm2pY) ;)

Comment: @brasofilo I was under the impression that the "Way of the Stack" was illustrated in this comment thread, at least until EAMann gave an Answer. :)

Comment: @EAMann The [ZIP format is mentioned too](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unzip_file) on Codex, so it is on topic here, right?

Comment: @toscho The ZIP format itself, no. But questions about zipping/unzipping from within WordPress potentially.

Comment: Okay, now I'm usually the Scope Police, and this is too pedantic even for me. I would say that a question that dovetails so precisely with the WordPress Coding Standards as this one not only is *on-topic* for WPSE, but also provides a great opportunity to expound upon the WordPress Coding Standard in question. This was a fastball down the middle; thankfully @EAMann recognized it, and swung for the fences.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This coding style is known as a Yoda Condition, and it's nothing specific to WordPress.  I've used the same style in C++, C#, and even JavaScript code.

The main benefit of a Yoda Condition is that it prevents accidental value assignment from a typo.  Consider the following (often-seen-in-the-wild) typo:

```
if ( $some_variable = 1 ) {
    // ...
}
```

This will always evaluate to `true`, but has the additional consequence of assigning the value `1` to `$some_variable`.  Sometimes this is intentional, though.  In WordPress specifically, you'll often see things like:

```
if ( $post = some_function( $_POST['id'] ) ) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

The point of this code *is* to assign a new value to the `$post` variable, and it works because the `some_function()` being used will return `false` on error.

Yoda Conditions (reversing the order of the `==` equality operator) protect you from accidentally assigning values when you didn't mean to.  If you make a mistake and only put one `=` in the code, you'll get an error because you can't assign *to* a regular value:

```
if ( 1 = $some_variable ) {
    // ...
}
```

Like I said, this is not unique to WordPress, or even to PHP, ***however*** it is part of the [required WordPress coding standards](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/#yoda-conditions).  If you're writing a plugin or theme for general distribution, or contributing to core, you need to know both what Yoda Conditions are and how to use them

Comment: Thank you for a very descriptive answer, much appreciated.